# Class design with SOLID Principle using C#

Tags: c#, design-patterns, solid-principles

Each elevator has a set of states.

• Maintenance: the elevator does not react to external signals (only to its own signals).

• Stand: the elevator is fixed on a floor. If it receives a call. And the elevator is on that floor, the doors open. If it is on another floor, it moves in that direction.

• Up: the elevator moves up. Each time it reaches a floor, it checks if it needs to stop. If so it stops and opens the doors. It waits for a certain amount of time and closes the door (unless someting is moving through them. Then it removes the floor from the request list and checks if there is another request. If so the elevator starts moving again. If not it enters the state stand.

• Down: like up but in reverse direction

NOTE: Some elevators don't start at bottom/first_floor esp. in case of sky scrappers. min_floor & max_floor are two additional attributes for Elevator.

My demo design:

```
public abstract class Elevator
{
    protected bool[] floorReady;
    protected int CurrentFloor = 1; 
    protected int topfloor; 
    protected ElevatorStatus Status = ElevatorStatus.STOPPED; //ElevatorStatus is enum

    protected virtual void Stop(int floor){}
    protected virtual void Descend(int floor)  {}
    protected virtual void Ascend(int floor) {}
    protected virtual void StayPut () {}
    protected virtual void FloorPress (int floor){}

}

interface ILogger
{
    void RegisterLog(string Message)
}

public FileLogger : ILogger
{
    void RegisterLog(string Message)
    {
        //Custom Code
    }
}
public class MyElevator : Elevator
{
    // All method overrride for base
}

//Client class
class program
{
    public static void main()
    {
     //DI for calling Looging

    }
}
```

Can somebody help me to design my classes which satisfy all the SOLID principle..

Thanks in advance...I want to design a Elevator Simulator using SOLID principles.

Comment: Welcome!  Sorry we are not here to write code for you.  Why not make yourself a nice cup of tea; read up on SOLID; perform some experiments and see how it pans out.  If you run into a specific problem, come back here and post about it.  Wishing you well! :)

Comment: Let me upload my try into GitHub and share the link here... Is that sounds good?

Comment: It's great that you have code to show.  Can you just post the minimal amount here by [editing](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/37266529/edit) your question?  Peeps generally won't look at foreign sites or code that is too long.  Thanks buddy

Comment: My Question is in my design Elevator class has a lot of Responsibility. Does it violets SRP?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at the [state pattern](http://www.dofactory.com/net/state-design-pattern).

By using it you move the business rules for moving the elevator to each specific state. So instead of using an Enum you let each state determine what to do next (like which state to use for the next action).

It also allows you to add new functionality (by adding more states) without modifying the elevator class (which is important from the SOLID perspective).